# How can we identify the timezone of date & time we are getting in MS Graph API response?

Tags: microsoft-graph-onenote

I am getting the following response from MS Graph API while fetching all sections.

```
            (
                [id] => 0-92b00000!86-AAAAAAAAAAAF1FC8!132
                [self] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/testtt
                [createdDateTime] => 2021-03-19T09:37:35Z
                [title] => ABCDEF
                [createdByAppId] => 
                [contentUrl] => https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/aaaaa
                [lastModifiedDateTime] => 2021-03-19T09:37:49Z
                
            )
```

In the above part of response, I want to identify the timezone of the server or this "lastModifiedDateTime".

Advance thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The "Z" suffix on the `lastModifiedDateTime` field means the timestamp is in [UTC, or Coordinated Universal Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), sometimes called "[Zulu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones)".

> The timestamp represents date and time information using ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time. For example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2014 is 2014-01-01T00:00:00Z.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/page?view=graph-rest-1.0)